# AttributeError: module 'dis' has no attribute '_unpack_opargs' While Building Python 3.6 executable using CX_FREEZE

Tags: python, python-3.x, build, cx-freeze

I have been trying to Convert my Python 3.6 Programs into.EXE. When I build using cx_Freeze. It generates the following error. (See Log Below)

I was earlier working with Kivy Module but after the build failed repeatedly I tried it with simple Hello World Program still, It failed.

My setup file contains `from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable` import statement,

When I build through `python setup.py build` It generates this log.

```
F:\Python\test>python setup.py build
running build
running build_exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 7, in 
    executables = [Executable('hello.py')])
  File "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freez
e\dist.py", line 349, in setup
    distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\distutils\core.py", li
ne 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", li
ne 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", li
ne 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\distutils\command\buil
d.py", line 135, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", lin
e 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", li
ne 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freez
e\dist.py", line 219, in run
    freezer.Freeze()
  File "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freez
e\freezer.py", line 621, in Freeze
    self.finder = self._GetModuleFinder()
  File "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freez
e\freezer.py", line 333, in _GetModuleFinder
    self.path, self.replacePaths)
  File "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freez
e\finder.py", line 150, in init
    self._AddBaseModules()
  File "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freez
e\finder.py", line 161, in _AddBaseModules
    self.IncludeModule("traceback")
  File "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freez
e\finder.py", line 645, in IncludeModule
    namespace = namespace)
  File "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freez
e\finder.py", line 310, in _ImportModule
    deferredImports, namespace = namespace)
  File "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freez
e\finder.py", line 403, in _InternalImportModule
    parentModule, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freez
e\finder.py", line 474, in _LoadModule
    self._ScanCode(module.code, module, deferredImports)
  File "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freez
e\finder.py", line 544, in _ScanCode
    method = dis._unpack_opargs if sys.version_info[:2] >= (3, 5) \
AttributeError: module 'dis' has no attribute '_unpack_opargs'
```

F:\Python\test>

Thanks for your Help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1.** Open 
File `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py`:

**2.** Change (at `line 544`) this:

```
   method = dis._unpack_opargs if sys.version_info[:2] >= (3, 5) \
   else self._UnpackOpArgs
```

to:

```
   method = self._UnpackOpArgs
```

**3.** Save the file and try to build again ;)

Comment: This worked perfectly! Can you please tell me how you knew the solution?

Comment: So, in your cmd output the last line of call stack is exception description: 
`File "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freez
e\finder.py", line 544, in _ScanCode
    method = dis._unpack_opargs if sys.version_info[:2] >= (3, 5) \
AttributeError: module 'dis' has no attribute '_unpack_opargs`

so it means called function 'dis' takes some unexpected argument... i just open file to see that function and see: i can hook it just removed that dis. part of that block.)))