# AttributeError: module 'dis' has no attribute '_unpack_opargs'

Tags: debugging, console, pycharm

```
File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_comm\pydev_server.py", line 34, in handle
    self.processor.process(iprot, oprot)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\thrift.py", line 266, in process
    self.handle_exception(e, result)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\thrift.py", line 254, in handle_exception
    raise e
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\thrift.py", line 263, in process
    result.success = call()
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\thrift.py", line 228, in call
    return f(*(args.__dict__[k] for k in api_args))
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_console_utils.py", line 304, in loadFullValue
    from _pydev_bundle.pydev_console_commands import ThriftGetValueAsyncThreadConsole
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_console_commands.py", line 2, in <module>
    from _pydevd_bundle.pydevd_comm import PyDBDaemonThread
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 96, in <module>
    from _pydevd_bundle import pydevd_bytecode_utils
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_bytecode_utils.py", line 105, in <module>
    _unpack_opargs = dis._unpack_opargs
AttributeError: module 'dis' has no attribute '_unpack_opargs'
```

Whenever I opened python console in pycharm, iam getting above error. I tried to find the error from the python dis.py located in "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\dis.py, but didn't find '_unpack_opargs' function. where it actually called from the location of the python file "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_bytecode_utils.py". Please help to get rid of this problem.

Actually what I thought is, above case is different from the 
[AttributeError: module 'dis' has no attribute '_unpack_opargs' While Building Python 3.6 executable using CX_FREEZE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42098453/attributeerror-module-dis-has-no-attribute-unpack-opargs-while-building-py) post

Comment: Do you have custom module/package named `dis` in your project?

Comment: No, I observed above problem in "PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1" version.

Answer (score 0):

```
if IS_PY3K:
    long = int

try:
    _unpack_opargs = dis._unpack_opargs
except AttributeError:
    def _unpack_opargs(code):
       n = len(code)
```

steps:

1. remove below code line from `if` condition.

```
_unpack_opargs = dis._unpack_opargs
```

2. remove `else` condition and replace with `try cache` looks like above code.